# OpenCV : Fast Template matching algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, template-matching

I am currently trying to look for an image inside a video. The main goal is to follow some actions on the video like a pressed button or a pop-up window displayed on the screen.

The code I'm using uses OpenCV Template Matching function:

```
    // For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
    if( matchingMethod  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || matchingMethod == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
        matchLoc = minLoc;
    else
        matchLoc = maxLoc;

    if( !((matchLoc.x == 0) && (matchLoc.y == 0)) || maxVal >= 0.8)
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

The test is done with these two templates :

[image: Template n°1]
[image: Template n°2]

And the full image is a 3840x2160 image (i can't but the whole image since it is too big in bmp):

1) The question is how is it possible that for two templates with very few pixels of difference the algorithm can detect the first one but completely skip the second one ?
2) Is it possible that color depth could cause problems in the detection ?

- Both templates are loaded as BMP files in 24 bits depth. The source image is converted in 24 bits depth.
- Threshold is set to 0.92 for good accuracy
- MaxLevels is set to 1 for a very good accuracy since 2 does not find any matches

Thank your for your help and advices

Answer (score 0):

For those who maybe have the same issue, I just had to manage the return value differently.

Instead of

```
if( !((matchLoc.x == 0) && (matchLoc.y == 0)) || maxVal >= 0.8)
        return TRUE;
```

Which returns true as soon as potential match (80% match) has been found.

Now I return true only if the maxVal is superior than 0.99 which means very high match.

```
if( maxVal >= 0.99)
        return TRUE;
```

Second element I've changed is the threshold value which is used to classify the pixel values. I've decreased this value to 0.82 instead of 0.94 to get more possible matches and then filter with the maxVal value.